# Como funciona la sentencia for...in en javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

Buenas, me ha surgido una duda con la función `for...in` de javascript, y no se si es porque la estoy usando mal, pero no me funciona. Estoy intentando aplicar a varios elementos del DOM con `querySelectorAll` e intento aplicar a todos los elementos el estilo con el `for...in` de esta manera;

```js
var capas = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (var i in capas) {
    capas[i].style.transition = 'all 2s';
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

La consola me marca que `capas[i].style` es undefined y no entiendo por qué. El problema lo he resuelto con el método `forEach()`

```
capas.forEach(function (capas) {
   capas.style.transition = 'all 2s';
});
```

por lo que mi duda es respecto al uso del `for...in` (que no he visto por ningún lado que este obsoleto).

¿Estoy usando mal la sentencia o estoy haciendo un mal uso de ella? ¿Por qué me marca undefined los elementos?

Comment: En un `for .. in` no es como un `for` en el que la variable `i` accede a la posicion del array, si no que en tu caso , `i` **es** el elemento en el que estas actualemente del  objeto `capas`

Comment: O sea, que resulta undefined porque no estoy en ninguno entiendo.

Comment: No. Como comento en mi respuesta `i` va a tener el nombre de las propiedades y métodos del objeto `capas` devuelto por `querySelectorAll`, que no es un array

Comment: Si ya he visto tu respuesta, el comentario era anterior a que respondieras

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema no es cómo funciona la instrucción `for...in`, si no cómo funciona el método `querySelectorAll`.

Este método no devuelve un array, devuelve un objeto `NodeList` con una serie de propiedades ('0', '1', '2', ...) que contienen cada uno de los elementos del resultado, una propiedad `length` con el número de elementos totales y otros métodos (`item`, `entries`, `forEach`,...).

Al recorrer el objeto con un `for...in` lo que haces es ir accediendo a cada una de las propiedades y métodos del objeto como puedes ver en este ejemplo.

Efectivamente, la mejor manera de recorrer los elementos de un objeto `NodeList` es utilizar el método `forEach` implementado en el propio objeto.

```js
var capas = document.querySelectorAll('div');

console.log(capas);

for (var i in capas){
  console.log(i);
}

capas.forEach(function (item){
  item.style.transition = 'all 2s';
});
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

Comment: Vale ya entiendo, muy esclarecedora tu respuesta. Mi fallo era dar por hecho que el querySelectorAll me estaba devolviendo un Array.

Answer (score 0):

Te marca undefined porque i es el valor del elemento del array y al poner capas[i] estás intentando usarlo como índice del array.

Para que funcione correctamente debe tener esta forma, tomando tu ejemplo:

```
var capas = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (var i in capas) {
    i.style.transition = 'all 2s';
}
```

En cada iteración i hace referencia a un elemento div

Comment: No. Como comento en mi respuesta `capas` no es un array, y con el `for...in` lo que se obtiene en la variable `i` es el nombre de las diferentes propiedades y métodos del objeto `capas`.

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que he visto, estas son las 2 formas más faciles

Todos los métodos ya sea `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementsByTagName`, `querySelectorAll` devuelven un HTMLCollection, que es parecido un array, en v**erdad lo único parecido es que ambos pueden ser iterado**s, osea que tienen indices`(elemento[0], elemento[1], etc)` , pero no tiene los métodos de este. Entonces `Array.from()` crea un array, a partir de un objeto iterable, como lo es HTMLCollection o también `for...of` que no necesita crear un array, sino que este ya puede tratarlo como un array

```js
var capas = document.querySelectorAll("div");

for(var div of capas) div.innerHTML = `Soy un div con id: ${div.id}`;


var array = Array.from(capas);

for(var i in array) array[i].style.color = "blue";
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```